# How does peewee's get method knows how to generate where clause?

Tags: python, peewee

Python's peewee orm library allows me to query database using the `get` method like this:

```
grandma = Person.get(Person.name == 'Grandma L.')
```

This query will filter the resultset based on Person's name doing a sql `where` behind the scenes.

I know the expression `Person.name == 'Grandma L.'` is evaluated first and the `get` method receives just a boolean value.

How does the `get` method inspect it's arguments to detect that the filter needs to be applyed to the 'name' field ?

PS: I read peewee's source but couldn't have any clue how it does that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know the expression `Person.name == 'Grandma L.'` is evaluated first and the `get` method receives just a boolean value.

I don't know Peewee specifically but I do know how this sort of thing is done.

Basically, the second part of your sentence isn't true. `name` is of a custom type. Its `__eq__` method doesn't return just a Boolean value, but rather an object that contains information on what comparison was actually done. (This class might even derived from `bool` so it works like a Boolean in other contexts.) Its other rich comparison methods are similar.

But how does `Person.name` know that its name is `name`? The answer to *that* is that `Person` probably doesn't actually have a `name` attribute. Instead, it has a `__getattr__()` method that returns the `name` object, which is the custom class that has the `__eq__` method I just described.

Since `Person.__getattr__()` receives the name of the attribute, it can bake that name into the value it returns for `name`. Then the custom `__eq__` method on `name` returns a Boolean-like object that contains some representation of `name == 'Grandma L.'` inside it. And `Person.get()` uses this representation to put together the query.

Comment: Awesome. That gives me some clues where to read peewee's source. Thanks.

Comment: If Peewee is anything like the other ORMs (and [it is](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/quickstart.html#model-definition)), then `__getattr__` is not at play, but column/field objects as class attributes, defined in the model class. And those get the name from the attribute with some metaclass handling. In recent enough Python a metaclass will not be necessary for that anymore, as descriptors may define [`__set_name__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__set_name__) for that.

Comment: Sweet, that's a much better way to do it. But the main point is that field objects need to know their own name somehow.

Comment: Aye, that's handled during class construction by the metaclass. In case of peewee, [`BaseModel`](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/blob/master/peewee.py#L4822).